# Ping IP address routed to wrong destination

Tags: networking, router, routing, ping

In short, what are the possible reasons that `ping 192.168.1.18` will be redirected to `192.168.1.199` (or some other random IP addresses in `192.168.1.x`)?

--

So here is the full story.

I have a network printer at home, a NAS, and three computers.  Network setup looks like this:
[image: Network diagram]

One day, one of the computers failed to connect to the printer.  Later on I found that pinging from that computer resulted in weird results:

```
C:\>ping 192.168.1.8

Pinging 192.168.1.8 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.8: bytes=32 time=4ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64
Reply from 192.168.1.8: bytes=32 time=2ms TTL=64

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 2ms, Maximum = 4ms, Average = 2ms

C:\>ping 192.168.1.18

Pinging 192.168.1.18 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 192.168.1.199: Destination host unreachable.   <------- why .199 instead of .18 ??
Reply from 192.168.1.199: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.199: Destination host unreachable.
Reply from 192.168.1.199: Destination host unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.18:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),  <---- and why received=4 but not lost?

C:\>
```

The problem appears to be irrelevant of which wireless AP I connect to.  Also, I don't see the same problem from other computers at home.

--

These info should be irrelevant.  I put it here just in case it gives a hint.

- Router: Asus RT-AC88U + Asus RT-AC68U
- Printer: HP Color LaserJet Pro
- OS: Windows 10 (other computers at home are running Windows 10 & 11)

Comment: What device is `192.168.1.199` ? Is it the second router/WAP? How are these two Asus routers connected with each other? Could you add the routing table of the computer with the issues?

Comment: "random" addresses telling you your destination is unreachable is usually your gateway or router chiming in. I would suspect that it is your "AiMesh node" router.

Comment: 192.168.1.199 is probably the IP address of the device you're performing the "ping" from. Its local IP address reports that it cannot reach the target address. Otherwise the only way a "different" address can get in between you and the target is when the local address (where you ping from) is in a different subnet from the target address and the ping needs to go through a router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing gets "redirected", you are just misinterpreting the output of the ping command.

> why .199 instead of .18

This is the first misinterpretation. It says `Reply from 192.168.1.199`. In layman's terms: The response ("from `192.168.1.199`") comes either from the device doing the pinging (this occurs if no router is involved, e.g. if the destination devices is on the same subnet as the device doing the pinging) or from a router "responsible" for the destination's IP/subnet (if the destination device is on a different subnet and has to be routed). If you think about it, it can't be a reply from `.18` since that device is unreachable therefore it couldn't give a reply.

> why received=4 but not lost?

This is the second misinterpretation, `Reply from *.*.*.*: Destination host unreachable` is not counted as `lost` but as `received` (after all it says "`Reply from...`"). The output `Request timed out` will count as `lost`.

You can test it by pinging a connected device on your LAN and unplugging the destination device while pinging is in progress. Then you will get `Request timed out`. If you clear your ARP table (`arp -d *` in Windows) and ping the device again you should get the `Destination host unreachable` message. This is, again in layman's terms, because after clearing the ARP table there will be no more MAC address associated with the IP address so the ping "can not be sent out".

Yes, I agree this isn't very intuitive taken your expectation (and probable the expectation of most other users), but it makes more or less sense if you take into account how it works underneath (ARP resolution, routing etc.).

Comment: Thanks.  You are correct - `.199` was the IP address of the device doing the pinging.  I did not aware of that.

Comment: Your welcome, hope I could provide a little insight into networking. It's helpful to have a little background knowledge, even as a "regular user".